# Generalized models of set theory

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, forcing

The forcing method can be viewed as building a Boolean-valued model of set theory. Some generalizations include Heyting algebra/sheaf/lattice-valued model. However, it seems these generalizations are mostly applied in the context of non-classical logic, e.g. *Non-classical Models of ZF* by Martinez and Venturi. Have these methods been used to prove consistency results in classical logic? Or is there a formal or informal argument for why that will not work?

Another candidate might be continuous logic. By design it is mainly intended for studying analysis, but I suppose it also makes sense for set theory? What is a nontrivial example of a continuous model of ZFC?

Comment: The models of ZFC in continuous logic are the same as the models in usual first order logic, this should be true because the metric is built in to the syntax. It seems somewhat possible to me that there could be a connection between boolean valued models of ZFC and continuous logic, but I don't think anything is known along those lines.

Comment: If $M$ is a Heyting-valued model of ZFC, will it not in fact be Boolean-valued, as it has to validate excluded middle (or at least very many instances of it)? It seems like nothing is lost by working with Boolean algebras, rather than Heyting algebras, since we want to model classical logic.

Comment: @ErikWalsberg Could you elaborate on or provide a reference for "the metric is built in to the syntax"? I asked about continuous logic because of Keisler randomization, and it looks sort of similar to Boolean-valued model. There is also this [paper](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/scott67.pdf) by Scott; I can't really tell if his approach should be classified as Boolean-valued model or randomization.

Comment: @AndrejBauer What does ZFC have to do with excluded middle? Do you mean for $M$ to be useful for independence proof in classical logic it'd better be Boolean-valued?

Comment: @Kushi: the axiom of choice implies excluded middle.